# how to not parse double quotes within double quotes

Tags: php

Hello there :) I have a script in PHP that creates a file (with the function "file_put_contents()") , and it will put the contents of a PHP file within the file it just created. Within the PHP file, there are double quotations, so as i try to implement the code that i want to put into this newly made PHP file, it has double quotations, and the way how file_put_contents works is the second part of it uses double quotations as well.

To put it into perspective, this is how it goes: `file_put_contents('file.php',"code with "" in it")`
 so as you can see, the double quotations get in the way of the PHP files double quotes.

My question is, how do i get the text within the quotes to not parse?
Thanks

Comment: Try: `file_put_contents('file.php',"code with \"\" in it")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use `\` [more info](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)**

```
file_put_contents('file.php',"code with \"\" in it")
```

**or use `'` to quote second param**

```
file_put_contents('file.php','code with "" in it')
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the string which contains double quotes in a string literal defined using single quotes.

```
file_put_contents('file.php','code with "" in it');
```

Answer (score 0):

"Escaping" is what you're looking for. As always, the manual holds all your answers:

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the double quotes like this : `file_put_contents('file.php',"code with \"\" in it")`

For more information : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score -1):

Try using addslashes("codewith dowble quotes") to over come this issue

Comment: `addslashes()` will add actual slashes to the string instead of encoding the characters.