# Python3 Double Quote Parsing and Detection

Tags: regex, python-3.x, text

I am trying to detect certain text characters in a .txt document.

I am unable to detect: "" , but I can detect ".

Fake text I'm searching 'quote_test.txt'

```
"This is a test of the :: failure";"123";"Joe"
"This test should have failed on the above";"456";"Kathy ::"
"This is also a problem : they say";"789 "" test";"Jim"
"So is a , evidently when in a field";"543 :";"Mary"
"Will have to think about \"\" as a search";",475::";"Sue"
"Which is similar to the issue with " I think";"9463";"Toby"
```

The script is:

```
import csv
import re

fail_text = re.compile('(:|::|,|""|")') # "" is not detected

with open("quote_test.txt") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=';')

    for numx, line in enumerate(reader):
        for numy, column in enumerate(line):          
            m = re.search(fail_text, column)
            if m:
                print('Line {} Column {} has {} in {}'.format(
                    numx, numy, m.group(), column)
                )
```

The output looks like this, not detecting the "" in the text:

```
Line 0 Column 0 has : in This is a test of the :: failure
Line 1 Column 2 has : in Kathy ::
Line 2 Column 0 has : in This is also a problem : they say
Line 2 Column 1 has " in 789 " test
Line 3 Column 0 has , in So is a , evidently when in a field
Line 3 Column 1 has : in 543 :
Line 4 Column 0 has " in Will have to think about \\" as a search"
Line 4 Column 1 has , in ,475::
Line 5 Column 0 has " in Which is similar to the issue with  I think"
```

Originally I escaped the [text like this Stack solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173874/how-to-not-parse-double-quotes-within-double-quotes) out of habit, that didn't work.

Comment: I think the issue is with how the double quotes are being handled in re.compile, since: `fail_text = re.compile('::')` works to find :: but  `fail_text = re.compile('""')` does not.

Comment: What happens if you escapre the double quotes? `fail_text = re.compile('(:|::|,|\"\"|")')`

Comment: `re.compile('(:|::|\"\"|,|")') ` and this `re.compile('\"\"')` - doesn't pick up the ""

Comment: If you look at your output, your RE doesn't detect "::" (double colon). If double-double quote or double colon isn't significant, then just use

    fail_text = re.compile('(::?|,|""?)')

Comment: How comes the double quotes in your text are escaped, while all the single quotes are not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by setting the escape character in csv.reader() to `escapechar='\\'` and by changing the regex to `""?`

```
def delimiter_check():

    fail_text = re.compile('(::?|This|,|""?)')

    with open("quote_test.txt") as fp:
        reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', escapechar='\\')

        for numx, line in enumerate(reader):
            for numy, column in enumerate(line):          
                m = re.search(fail_text, column)
                if m:
                    print('Line {} Column {} has {} in {}'.format(
                        numx, numy, m.group(), column)
                    )
```

If the double quote in the text is escaped like this: `\"\"` then the script should find the double quote.

```
Line 4 Column 0 has "" in Will have to think about "" as a search
```